# Clearfix-Bug with negative margin

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I noticed a problem with the "default" clearfix everyone is using. For some reason the negative margin on the `.gallery` breaks it. I could not find any appropriate solution. The ones I found will interfere with other parts of my page.

So I need to have a fix only for the clearfix itself.

Also another CSS-solution which can be added to the `.gallery` and is **not** `overflow: hidden` will be - let's say: OK.

Thanks!

[image]

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -20px -20px 0; /* remove margins caused by inner items */
}

/* ##### Please fix this clearfix ##### */
.gallery:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}

.gallery .galleryItem {
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  float: left;
}



/* ----- do not edit below - this part contains prerequisites ----- */

.teaser {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #444;
}
.teaser .title {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #555;
}
.teaser + .teaser {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.teaser:nth-child(1) .galleryItem {
  background: #cc6600;
}
.teaser:nth-child(2) .galleryItem {
  background: #cc0000;
}
.teaser:nth-child(3) .galleryItem {
  background: #00cc00;
}
.teaser:nth-child(4) .galleryItem {
  background: #00cc00;
}
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#sidebar {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 380px;
}
.tooltip {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #eee !important;
  color: #333;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
}
.tooltip:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -11px;
  border-width: 11px 11px 11px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #eee transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  
  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="title">This has only a wrong "padding-top"</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="title">Here additionally the clearfix does not work like expected</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="thisIsAWorkaround">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="galleryItem"></div>
        <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="title">This is like it should, but has an additional DIV as workaround =/</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="tooltip title">This one is like it should (has same paddings to all sides)</div>
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Same on **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwowaa)** (but with LESS =)

Comment: Why not overflow: hidden;? I've been using for ages and never had a problem with it.

Comment: I got some other elements like popouts/flyouts/navigation arrows within that gallery which will be cut off.

Answer (score 3):

Here- you dont need the clearfix- simply add e.g. `display:inline-block` to `.gallery` in order to force a new [**block formatting context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

> A block formatting context is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a
>   Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs
>   and in which floats interact with each other.

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -20px -20px 0;
  /* remove margins caused by inner items */
}
/* ##### Please fix this clearfix ##### */

.gallery {
 display:inline-block
}
.gallery .galleryItem {
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  float: left;
}
/* ----- do not edit below - this part contains prerequisites ----- */

.teaser {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #444;
}
.teaser .title {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #555;
}
.teaser + .teaser {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.teaser:nth-child(1) .galleryItem {
  background: #cc6600;
}
.teaser:nth-child(2) .galleryItem {
  background: #cc0000;
}
.teaser:nth-child(3) .galleryItem {
  background: #00cc00;
}
.teaser:nth-child(4) .galleryItem {
  background: #00cc00;
}
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#sidebar {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 380px;
}
.tooltip {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #eee !important;
  color: #333;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
}
.tooltip:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -11px;
  border-width: 11px 11px 11px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #eee transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">

  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="title">This has only a wrong "padding-top"</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="title">Here additionally the clearfix does not work like expected</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="thisIsAWorkaround">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="galleryItem"></div>
        <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="title">This is like it should, but has an additional DIV as workaround =/</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="tooltip title">This one is like it should (has same paddings to all sides)</div>
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
      <div class="galleryItem"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As I said in the question, overflow: hidden is NO solution. I got some popouts/flyouts within that gallery which will be cut off

Comment: @Möhre - see revised above, there are more than one way to set a BFC as noted in the linked article.

Comment: @SW40 - I tested the mentioned display modes. `display:table` seems the only one without any side effects up to now. (`display:inline-block` creates additional tiny margins). Additionally I had to add `width:100%` because table is "non-greedy" and `box-sizing:border-box` to not break existing paddings. Still does not behave exactly like a `block`, but maybe this is best solution if flex-box is not supported - Thx!

Comment: @SW40 would you mind to change your answer to table (because of less problems than on inline-block)? I think this will be "the better" using that one.